# How to load a timestamp variable from SQL Server in SSIS to pull from Teradata?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, variables, ssis, teradata

Running into an issue where I am getting this error in an SSIS package:

```
[ODBC Source [52]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '22008'. Native Error Code: -6760. [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-6760)Invalid timestamp.
```

What I am doing is passing a variable into a Teradata query that is pulled from SQL server.  All housed within a sequence container.

```
select cast(dateadd(day,1, max(date))AS datetime) DateStart from [table]
```

the desired output should be:

```
2022-06-08 00:00:00.000
```

While this is the result I am passing to the variable, SSIS is kicking this back with the error above.

Pretty stuck here, would love some input from the community.

Comment: Which version of ODBC driver? Maybe try passing the value as a character string (in that format) rather than datetime. Or use a DATE data type if the time portion is not significant.

Comment: _passing a variable into a Teradata_ The SQL you posted doesn't have a parameter placeholder. Your explanation doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 1):

You need this expression:

```
select Current_Timestamp(3);
```

Or if you want the day before, you would do this:

```
select to_char(Current_date()-1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI.SS.FF3');
```